# How can I add sort items into a fragment dialog?

Tags: sapui5

I have this fragment retrieve by this page https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableViewSettingsDialog/code

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <ViewSettingsDialog
    confirm="handleConfirm" id='viewSettingsDialogId'>

    <sortItems id="sortItemsId">

      <!-- <ViewSettingsItem text="Product" key="Name" selected="true" />
      <ViewSettingsItem text="Supplier" key="SupplierName" />
      <ViewSettingsItem text="Weight" key="WeightMeasure" />
      <ViewSettingsItem text="Price" key="Price" /> -->
    </sortItems>

  </ViewSettingsDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I want insert manually the sortItems in the control (or by data-binding in the xml-View).
How can I do it?

I try to do it by code in my controller:

```
//IF CLICK ON SETTINGS BUTTON
    handleViewSettingsDialogButtonPressed: function (oEvent) {
        if (!this._oDialog) {
          this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("apps.appIntra.fragment.settingDialog", this);
        }
        // toggle compact style
        jQuery.sap.syncStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact", this.getView(), this._oDialog);
        this._oDialog.open();

        var element=sap.ui.getCore().byId("sortItemsId");

        this.byId('sortItemsId').addSortItem(new sap.m.ViewSettingsItem({text:"field1", key:"Price"}));
        this.byId('sortItemsId').addSortItem(new sap.m.ViewSettingsItem({text:"field2", key:"PLUTO"}));
      },
```

But it not work...

I see this guide http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/02/20/sapui5-dialogwith-businesscard-as-xml-fragment-along-with-controller
but if I use

```
var element=sap.ui.getCore().byId("sortItemsId");
```

element value is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addSortItem` is a method that works on the `ViewSettingsDialog` and not on `sortItems`.

Therefore, as you have already provided the id `viewSettingsDialogId` for the `ViewSettingsDialog` control, in you controller you can do the following,

```
   var oViewSettingsDialog = sap.ui.getCore().byId("viewSettingsDialogId");
   oViewSettingsDialog.addSortItem(new sap.m.ViewSettingsItem({text:"field1",
                                   key:"Price"}));
    /* and so on... */
```

This would add the sort items into the `sortItems` list.